# How to offset moment.js time Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I got created time from MongoDB and I want add 6 hours for that. I want a visible button if now time less than after add 6 hours for created time. I use `moment.js`

```
timenow:moment().format('LT')
```

```
{this.state.timenow > moment(post.createdAt).format('LT')  &&
                  <Button
                    variant="outline-info"
                    className="cardbutton"
                    size="sm"
                    onClick={this.editPost.bind(this, post._id, post.message)}
                  >
                    Edit
                  </Button>}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:
`moment(time).add(x, 'hours')` where `time` is the time object you want to offset by x hours

Comment: You are welcome, glad I could be of help.